# 301 redirect special charecter issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

The URLs with special characters such as `é`, `ü` do not redirect correctly.

For example : `Redirect 301 /de/pages/schuhe_mit_schmaler_füßbreite http://www.mydomain.com/de/schuhe-für-schmale-füße/l/`

I already tried using the suggestions in [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002623/redirection-rules-with-special-characters), but it does not work for me.

working rule :
`Redirect 301 /de/pages/duo_latest http://www.mydomain.com/de/entdecken-sie-duo/neues/`

not working rule :
`Redirect 301 /fr/pages/duo_latest http://www.mydomain.com/fr/découvrez-duo/nouvelles/`

not working rule contain special character `é`

Comment: Redirect 301 /fr/pages/duo_latest http://www.mydomain.com/fr/découvrez-duo/nouvelles/

Comment: Any rules you are using in your .htaccess file

Comment: I update the question with working rule and not working rule Please see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the text editor you are using to save to your .htaccess file supports [UTF-8 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). If you are using Notepad, configure the settings so that it is not saving as ANSI.

If you cannot get it to save to UTF-8, create a completely new .htaccess file that is saved in UTF-8 and replace the old file with the new one.

Answer (score 1):

This works probably fine

```
 RewriteRule ^türen/(.*) http://google.de?$1 [L]
```

What is your problem? Can you post some more details

Comment: >>not working rule contain special character<< what is not working? get you an internal server error or does your browser don't understand the special character? please post your .htaccess rules for more understanding